# Neo4J CSV relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I am a Neo4J newbie and I have a simple CSV with source and dest IPs.  I'd like to create a relationship between nodes with the same labels.

Something like ... source_ip >> ALERTS >> dest_ip, or the reverse.

```
"dest_ip","source_ip" 
"130.102.82.16","54.231.19.32" 
"130.102.82.116","114.30.64.11" 
"130.102.82.116","114.30.64.11" 
...

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:///Users/me/Desktop/query_result.csv" AS csvLine  
CREATE (alert:Alert { source_ip: csvLine.source_ip, dest_ip: csvLine.dest_ip})

MATCH (n:Alert) RETURN n LIMIT 25

dest_ip 130.102.82.16 source_ip 54.231.19.32
```

....

This works fine.  My question is how I create the relationship between the labels inside the alerts?  I've tried and failed a slew of times.  I'm guessing I need to set up separate Nodes for Source and Dest and then link them, just unsure how.

Thanks in advance!

Peace,
Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create a constraint like this, to guarantee uniqueness and speed up the `MERGE` operation.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:Alert) ASSERT a.ip IS UNIQUE;
```

You can use as many `CREATE` statements as you want, and then `MERGE` the relationship, like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:///Users/me/Desktop/query_result.csv" AS csvLine  
MERGE (node1:Alert { ip: csvLine.source_ip })
MERGE (node2:Alert { ip: csvLine.dest_ip })
MERGE (node1)-[r:ALERT]->(node2)
```

By the by, I'd recommend using `MERGE` in most places to make sure you don't end up creating duplicates.   In this file, a certain IP address might be listed many times, you don't want a new node each time it's created, you probably want all references under that one IP address, hence `MERGE` here instead of `CREATE`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your graph model is something like

> (:source)-[:ALERT]->(:Destination)

The following Cypher query will create that relationship

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/me/Desktop/query_result.csv" AS csvLine 
CREATE (source:Source { ip: csvLine.source_ip })-[:ALERTS]->(dest:Destination { ip: csvLine.dest_ip})
```

Comment: You might get duplicate entries this way.